# customize the clang format

Tags: format, clang

I know I can create a .clang-format file, and use this per project, but what I'd really like is a way to set the default clang-format style to one of the available formats, so I can experiment with various styles across various projects.

I would think something like setting a clang-format-style variable to "llvm" or "mozilla".   Is soemthing like this possible?

Alternatively, can I do a key binding that calls clang-format-region specifying the formatting style?

Comment: What package does clang-format-region come from?

Comment: `clang-format-region` is part of the `clang-format.el` package iirc. Also, it seems like `clang-format-region` already accepts a third parameter being the formatting style. (The two first ones being start and end of the region.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-style=<string>` of `clang-format`:

> Coding style, currently supports: LLVM, Google, Chromium, Mozilla,
>   WebKit.
>
> Use -style=file to load style configuration from .clang-format
>   file located in one of the parent directories of the source file (or
>   current directory for stdin).
>
> Use -style="{key: value, ...}" to set
>   specific parameters, e.g.: -style="{BasedOnStyle: llvm, IndentWidth:
>   8}"

Define a function with a `style` forwarded to `clang-format-region`. Then, bind it to a key:

```el
(defun clang-format-region-mozilla (s e)
  (interactive
   (if (use-region-p)
       (list (region-beginning) (region-end))
     (list (point) (point))))
  (clang-format-region s e "Mozilla"))

(define-key c++-mode-map (kbd "C-<f10>") #'clang-format-region-mozilla)

(defun clang-format-region-llvm (s e)
  (interactive
   (if (use-region-p)
       (list (region-beginning) (region-end))
     (list (point) (point))))
  (clang-format-region s e "LLVM"))

(define-key c++-mode-map (kbd "C-<f11>") #'clang-format-region-llvm)
```

The upper example maps:

- <kbd>C-F10</kbd> to `clang-format-region` with the `"Mozilla"` style
- <kbd>C-F11</kbd> to `clang-format-region` with the `"LLVM"` style

Change the keys and the styles as it suits you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand. Did you actually try setting `clang-format-style`? By default it's set to `"file"`, so that it takes the style information from the .clang-format file.

You can keep it that way and create a .clang-format file with the [`BasedOnStyle`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) variable set to whatever style you want to inherit from, that way you retain the ability to use different styles on different projects (e.g. open source projects that might use a style different from your preferred).